# If $F(a)=\int_0^1\frac{x^a-1}{\ln x}dx$ why $F'(a)=\frac1{a+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

This is a step of an answer of a problem that I don't understand,

> Define $F(a)=\int_0^1\frac{x^a-1}{\ln x}dx$. Note that
> $$F'(a)=\int_0^1x^adx=\frac1{a+1}$$

I don't know how we get $F'(a)=\int_0^1x^adx$. In fact I know that $\frac d{da}(x^a-1)=x^a\times\ln(a)$ and it seems we plugged in $a$ in denominator of the fraction $\frac{x^a-1}{\ln x}$ and the result is $x^a$. I'm not sure if it is the step and why we are doing it.

Comment: Your derivative is incorrect. $\frac{d}{da}(x^a-1) = x^a \times \ln x$

Comment: @Ninad Munshi Oh I missed that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all $\frac d{da}(x^a-1)=x^a\times\ln(x)$. Secondly, you can interchange derivative and integral with the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to get

$$F'(a)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}\int_0^1\frac{x^a-1}{\ln x}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}\frac{x^a-1}{\ln x}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1x^a\,\mathrm dx.$$